# Lightbox Gallery + Do not show alt but div

Tags: javascript, html, gallery, lightbox

Here is the codepen: http://codepen.io/lkfmarketing/pen/XMdNEP

There is only one problem, which is that in the overlay the 'alt' text of the image is displayed. Instead I want to show a text from a div on each specific picture.

I have been Googling for solutions, but I can't find any lightbox galleries that are so simple to use, and do have this function I just mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

What div you want the text to be from?
In your code there is a line `var cap = $(this).attr("alt");`
That makes it show the alt. Just replace it with the div or a string that you want there. 
Eg: `var cap = "Test";` makes it show the word "Test" instead of the alt.

Comment: I want to have different text for each image, inside a div. The output of the text should not come from the 'alt' text, but from a div. The solution you mentioned will display "Test" on all images in the overlay.

Comment: I used that as an example to show how to change it, not how to get the div data. I wasnt able to find the div.

Comment: I will create the div by myself. So example for the first image: `<div class="imagetext">Output text that will be shown under the image in the overlay</div>`.

Comment: I guess I'm into something with this: `var cap = $(this).getElementById('test')`? :)